# fetch record from database according to date_of_birth in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I want to create a query for fetching records from database. In Manager Model, Manager Table has date_of_birth column. Query is:

```
   Manager.all.where(:date_of_birth => Date.now)
```

Through Query whole format of date_of_birth column compare to current date in Manager Controller's Index action.But my requirement is to compare month and day of date_of_birth column to today's day and month.How can I do that? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL methods `MONTH()` and `DAY()` for your query like this :

```
Manager.all
  .where("MONTH(date_of_birth) = (?)", Date.now.month)
  .where("DAY(date_of_birth) = (?)", Date.now.day)
```

Documentation :

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanku so much. after getting your answer I use this query `Manager.all.where("MONTH(date_of_birth) = (?) and DAY(date_of_birth) = (?)", Date.today.month ,Date.today.day)`

Comment: Yep, that generates the same sql request.